# Failing File I/O is_open() in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, file-io, qt-creator, fstream, ifstream

I'm using QtCreator 3.6.0 - Based on Qt 5.5.1 (Clang 6.1 (Apple), 64 bit).

I'm trying to read a text file but I keep on getting this error message,

> Unable to open file/Users/... ...

Here is the code extract,

```
string line;
    ifstream myfile ("Config.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

My 'Config.txt' file is in the same project folder where main.cpp is.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: print the cwd the program runs within.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code corresponding to the output ?

Comment: Did you try putting the file in the same folder as the generated executable?

Comment: QtCreator does not execute the program in the folder where your `main.cpp` is located.

Comment: Specify full path to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QtCreator, you should change the working directory to the directory containing Config.txt. You can find the "Working directory" setting for your executable via the sidebar "Projects" => "Build & Run" => "Run"

See: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html